# GenericDao, Class<T> is null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, generics, dao

I'm implementing GenericDao. I have problem with 2 methods - getAll() and getById(Long id), entity class has null value. It looks like the class is not setted. How Can I solve this problem ?

```
 @Repository
 public class GenericDaoImpl<T> implements GenericDao<T> {

private Class<T> clazz;

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setClazz(final Class<T> clazzToSet) {
    this.clazz = clazzToSet;
}

public T getById(final Long id) {
    return (T) this.getCurrentSession().get(this.clazz, id);
}

public List<T> getAll() {

    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(
            this.clazz);
    return criteria.list();

}
   protected final Session getCurrentSession() {
    return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  }
 }
```

PersonDao

```
    public interface PersonDao extends GenericDao<Person> { }
```

PersonDaoImpl

```
 @Repository("PersonDAO")
 public class PersonDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<Person> implements PersonDao {}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

   @Autowired
  private PersonDao personDao;


@Transactional
public List<Person> getAll() {

    return personDao.getAll();
}


@Transactional
public Person getById(Long id) {
    return personDao.getById(id);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set the `clazz` property of `PersonDao`.  This can be done by declaring a [post initialization callback](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) with the `@PostConstruct` annotation.

```
 @Repository("PersonDAO")
 public class PersonDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<Person> implements PersonDao {

      @PostConstruct
      public void init(){
         super.setClazz(Person.class);
      }
 }
```